# I am struggling to find a solution about scrolling while navigating between pages in Angular 9 project

Tags: routes, scrollbar, scrolltop, angular9

Let suppose i have one main page (view) that shows some records and another child page from where are displayed details of one of those record clicked from main view. When i try to navigate from details view to main view, the scrollbar will remain at the same position as it was earlier. I want to move scrollbar on the top of the page while navigating back. My project is just upgraded to **Angular 9.**

I was searching for any solution over stackoverflow, and i have tried some suggested solutions, but still not.

The most suggested solution is this:

RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' } // <-- HERE
)

I have tried it but still the same.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks in advance.